# Batch file to be converted in powershell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am new on powershell, I want to convert the following batch script into powershell. The reason why I want this conversion is because this script will be run on a server from my task scheduler and due to the fact that the cmd is not working with UNC paths I think that could be a good workaround.
This script is checking if there are 20 zip files in a folder and in case they are found then starts a python script to unzip them (mandatory)

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b  W:\XXX\XXX\*.zip ^| find /c /v ""') do (
   if /i %%a EQU 0 EXIT
   if /i %%a NEQ 20 timeout /t 300 /nobreak
   if /i %%a NEQ 20 Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File W:\XXX\XXX\powershellerrormail.ps1
   if /i %%a NEQ 20 EXIT
   if /i %%a EQU 20 (python W:\XXX\XXX\SSC_Unzipping.py)
pause)
EXIT
```

Comment: Here is a good starting point. Open the `powershell` terminal, then type `help` and start reading through the help pages. `:)`

Comment: Your presumption "cmd is not working with UNC paths" is not correct.

Comment: Perhaps "cmd" was shorthand for "command"? or ".cmd"? or "cmd.exe"? so I'm not presuming anything!